# Extract SCORM Quiz Data from SCORM Container

Tags: php, xml, flash, scorm, scorm2004

I have course videos published by Articulate that are SCORM-compliant (SCORM 2004).  Our client is looking for a new LMS that doesn't rely on Flash.  I'm looking to extract the course and quiz data (questions and answers, not results) so as to decouple it from all third-party software.  I will handle the quiz and presentations myself without Flash.

I'm looking to do a single run with the courses, pull the data, store it in the database, and finally discard the original files.

How can I accomplish this?  The presentation data is output in XML, but the quiz data is not.

I understand the point of SCORM is to facilitate easy transfer of course data from one system to another, but putting it in a compiled Flash package couldn't make this any more difficult.  Perhaps I'm missing something?

Kind regards,

Scott

**Solution**
Articulate quizzes include a file "data.swf."  The data is in the form of non-encrypted XML, so you can open it in your own flash app and send the data to the server to be parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Articulate quizzes include a file "data.swf." The data is in the form of non-encrypted XML, so you can open it in your own flash app and send the data to the server to be parsed.

Comment: The file data.swf is a binary file isn't it? Could you say how were you able to get XML data out of it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're really trying to do is reverse engineer the Articulate output to extract the quiz data that is embedded in there. That really doesn't have anything to do with SCORM.

Comment: I think I'm having a hard-time trying to determine what is SCORM, what is Articulate and what is Rustici.  From what I've gathered, Articulate outputs the data using a SCORM format that is read by the Rustici player and then that data is fed to the LMS?  I'm basically trying to allow our client to continue authoring content with Articulate, however, display the output in a way that doesn't rely on Flash and can work in mobile environments.  We're really not interested in maintaining SCORM compliance with our system.

Comment: Articulate is really tightly coupled with Flash, if you want to display the output in a non-Flash environment, you probably want to consider using a different authoring tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you have results, you may be able to extrapolate the info from the interaction data.

I've ran into this issue before - you're not going to find the question answer data in the manifest info.

There is an export to Word option in Articulate, however.  At least you'd be able to get the question and answers that way.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

De-coupling Articulate Courses from Flash ... that might be a bridge too far.  Whatever time you invest making that work is probably significantly more than adopting another tool.  There's a few out there that claim they generate good mobile content.